# How can I throw a runtime error in TFLite?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm getting a bug that only seems to happen when running my TFLite model on android (I can't replicate it in python).

```
Internal error: Failed to run on the given Interpreter: tensorflow/lite/kernels/gather_nd.cc:135 indices_has_only_positive_elements was not true.
```

To track it down, I'm trying to put in asserts into the code.  In my case:

```
tf.assert_greater(tf.reduce_min(maxima_ij_coords),  -1)
local_max_pixels = tf.cast(tf.gather_nd(image, maxima_ij_coords), tf.float32)
```

However - it seems these asserts do not work when running TFLite.  They do work as when running with eager execution.

Is there any direct way to throw a runtime error (preferably one with an informative message) in a tflite model?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that asserts are stripped out in TensorFlow Lite, since they would add overhead in production scenarios.
The best way to handle errors like this is to use the TF Lite error reporting APIs. You can call interpreter->ReportError() with a message, and it will be reported to the user however is appropriate for the platform (log on Android, exception on Python, etc).
In your specific case, you might want to add a check like:

```
if (tf.reduce_min(maxima_ij_coords) < 0) {
  interpreter->ReportError(
      "indices_has_only_positive_elements was not true.");
}
```

This will ensure users see a clear message, while not impacting performance in the success case.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I'm building the model in Python, so not sure what this `interpreter` object is supposed to be and cannot find any `ReportError` class/function.

Comment: The Interpreter class is part of the C++ API for TensorFlow Lite, and is used to run models on device.
The ReportError method is used to report runtime errors in a TFLite model. It's primarily intended for platform-specific error reporting (e.g. throwing an exception in Python, or logging on Android), so you won't find it in the main TensorFlow API.
If you're interested in using this from Python, you would need to use the TFLite C++ API directly via SWIG or similar.